# Dynamically creating models for a table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a migration that will dynamically create tables on fly per date.  Something like this:

```
class CreateCollectorPeriodTable < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.create_with(name)  
    create_table name.to_sym do |t|
      t.string :text, :limit => 1024
    end
  end 
end
```

I want to create a model that will access this migration..

I did read this: [Rails Generate Model from Existing Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986301/rails-generate-model-from-existing-table), but in another question someone explained why I shouldn't try and make one model fit many tables..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more the reasoning behind this? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class CreateCollectorPeriodTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  # name should be plural
  # i.e.: name = 'chickens'
  def self.create_with(name)  
    create_table name.to_sym do |t|
      t.string :text, :limit => 1024
    end
    model_file = File.join("app", "models", name.singularize+".rb")
    model_name = name.singularize.capitalize
    File.open(model_file, "w+") do |f|
      f << "class #{model_name} < ActiveRecord::Base\nend"
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: This will work. Only it seems to me almost identical to `rails g model <model-name> text:string`, so not sure what the use-case is.

Comment: @nathanvda, absolutely :) for me it is quite strange task