# Mysql table_creation helpers

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want to make an app which allows to create a table by using returned user input. For example when you go to my website and fill in a website name I want it to create a table which corresponds this website name.

Another question would be how to make this user input make a subdomain to my current domain like:

```
yourURL.MyURL.com
```

Comment: Why do you want to create tables based on user input? What will the schema for these tables look like? There is probably a better way of modeling this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can simply use create_table method from ActiveRecord::Migration, but i don't think that this is a good way. To deal with subdomains u can read and watch nice railscast about that http://asciicasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

Comment: I have watched the railscast and this did include the information I was looking for about the subdomain thanks for this! now I still need to find the helper method wich allows met to create tables and column using user input

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673591/dynamically-creating-models-for-a-table-in-rails